# How to get an absolutely positioned item inside a relatively positioned flexbox container to grow?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wwucLo3c/ I need the red div to be full width when there is no cyan div. And if there is they both have to be 50%.

Here's the container's CSS:

```
.container{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:blue;

    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    align-content:stretch;
}
```

And the item's:

```
.item{
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    flex:1 1 1;
    min-width:50%;
    height:10%;
}
```

Basically, i need an absolutely positioned item to grow if there is no other item at it's width and shrink if there is. Is it even possible? It seems like i tried every flexbox setting and nothing helped.

Comment: Do you need to have the items absolutely positioned?

Comment: Maybe [this way](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/wwucLo3c/1/)?

Comment: @Jackson Yes. In the project where i encountered this i can't do without absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it even possible?**

**No**, You cannot set flex layout properties(except order) to flex children with `position: absolute`

[**Absolutely-Positioned Flex Children**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items)

> An absolutely-positioned child of a flex container does not
>   participate in flex layout. However, it does participate in the
>   reordering step (see order), which has an effect in their painting
>   order.

---

**Solution:**

1. Remove `position: absolute` and change the position using `margin-top`.
2. `flex: 1 1 1` is incorrect. The last value `flex-basis` does not accept unit-less values(except 0 and auto)

[**Updated JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/wwucLo3c/5/)

```css
body {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: stretch;
}
.item {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  height: 10%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  min-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Multiple items</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" style="background:tomato"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background:cyan"></div>
</div>
<h2>Single item</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" style="background:tomato"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to use the correct syntax for the `flex` style.

```
.item {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

It is easier to do this using `position: relative` on the items instead
See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wwucLo3c/2/)

If it is necessary to use position absolute then you would need to wrap the items in a wrapper and position that absolutely instead.
See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wwucLo3c/4/)